# Dont want to have to start mongod with `sudo mongod`

Tags: macos, mongodb

I just downloaded mongodb onto my brandy new MacBookAir with OS X 10.9.5 by doing `brew install mongodb`.

I tried to run `mongod` from Terminal and it said "no /data/db" so I created it with `sudo mkdir /data` and `sudo mkdir /data/db`.

Running mongod now I get "Unable to create/open lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied" but I can run it perfectly fine with `sudo mongod`.

How can I make it so that I don't have to run mongod with sudo, but instead just as simply `mongod`?

(I had it like that on my last computer but do not remember what I did at all, and that computer was all messed up anyway.)

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /data/db
```

then

```
sudo chown -R `id -u` /data/db
```

The `-R` makes the command recursive; I had previously tried both `sudo chmod 777 /data/db` and `` sudo chown `id -u` /data/db `` as instructed on other StackOverflow answers but they failed.

(PS I'm sorry I know this is a very old question but I found it while trying to look for an answer to my problem; and since I managed to solve it I thought I'd put this here for anyone in the future. Also I'm not sure which of those two commands made the difference, but it worked.)

Answer (score 5):

Simple Start it with

```
 mongod --dbpath ~/.mongodb/data --logpath ~/.mongodb/mongod.log --fork
```

after you did an

```
mkdir ~/.mongodb
```

The problem is that the default  dbpath `/data/mongodb` was created for root.

Another option would be to do a

```
chown <your username here> -R /data/mongodb
```

And run mongod with the default paths.

As an alternative to running MongoDB directly under OSX, you might want to have a look at[m202docker](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/mwmahlberg/m202docker/), which allows you to run MongoDB in a (thin) virtualized environment. There are other Docker images for MongoDB as well.

*Disclaimer: I created the m202docker image, so I am propably biased*