# Having trouble installing and using mongodb. on my macosx and a readonly /data/db

Tags: mongodb, terminal

I want to install Mongodb for my next online web course but the thing is I'm having so much issues. I have been installing and uninstall mongodb so many times I think it's conflicting with temp ... Can someone guide me to the process please, really would appreciate it.

The error when running mongodb:

> 017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I STORAGE [initandlisten] exception in
>   initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only
>   directory: /data/db, terminating 2017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I
>   NETWORK [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
>   2017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I NETWORK [initandlisten] shutdown: going
>   to flush diaglog... 2017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I CONTROL
>   [initandlisten] now exiting 2017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I CONTROL
>   [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100 –

I tried installing it on homebrew , nothing happen, I tried installing it manually still having troubles.. I know my basic like cd,ls,rm,pwd,touch, when using the terminal, If theres process that i can wipe everything associate with mangodb in my Macbook and install it again i have no problem.

found out that  /data/db is readonly

Comment: what exactly you got with: brew install mongodb

Comment: I get "Warning: mongodb 3.4.5 is already installed"

Comment: So it s already installed,  what is returning by typing: mongod

Comment: 017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
2017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100

Comment: That's the problem, /data/db is readonly. Could you modify your question with these details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB is already installed but you have some issue launching it.

> 017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I STORAGE [initandlisten] exception in
>   initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only
>   directory: /data/db, terminating 2017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I
>   NETWORK [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
>   2017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I NETWORK [initandlisten] shutdown: going
>   to flush diaglog... 2017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I CONTROL
>   [initandlisten] now exiting 2017-07-02T10:31:41.547-0400 I CONTROL
>   [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100 –

Change the permission of /data/db

```
sudo chown -R `id -un` /data/db
```

Now you should start the daemon without problem:`mongod`

then connect with your mongo client by typing. `mongo`

> ok.. then got this. 2017-07-02T10:50:39.069-0400 I CONTROL
>   [initandlisten] options: { repair: true, storage: { dbPath: "/data/db"
>   } } 2017-07-02T10:50:39.069-0400 W - [initandlisten] Detected unclean
>   shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
>   2017-07-02T10:50:39.069-0400 E NETWORK [initandlisten] Failed to
>   unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied
>   2017-07-02T10:50:39.069-0400 I - [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
>   at src/mongo/util/net/listen.cpp 195 2017-07-02T10:50:39.070-0400 I -
>   [initandlisten] ***aborting after fassert() failure

your /tmp is maybe not readable, try:

```
chmod 1777 /tmp
```

Comment: Got this when i use your code....2017-07-02T10:43:00.796-0400 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
2017-07-02T10:43:00.797-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied
2017-07-02T10:43:00.797-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578 at src/mongo/util/net/listen.cpp 195
2017-07-02T10:43:00.797-0400 I -        [initandlisten]

Comment: when i type mongo.. got this... 2017-07-02T10:45:19.953-0400 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-07-02T10:45:19.953-0400 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6

Comment: type: mongod --dbpath /data/db --repair

Comment: ok.. then got this. 2017-07-02T10:50:39.069-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { repair: true, storage: { dbPath: "/data/db" } }
2017-07-02T10:50:39.069-0400 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
2017-07-02T10:50:39.069-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied
2017-07-02T10:50:39.069-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578 at src/mongo/util/net/listen.cpp 195
2017-07-02T10:50:39.070-0400 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure

Comment: type: chmod 1777 /tmp , then retry

Comment: getting this now... 017-07-02T11:04:58.194-0400 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
2017-07-02T11:04:58.194-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied
2017-07-02T11:04:58.194-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578 at src/mongo/util/net/listen.cpp 195
2017-07-02T11:04:58.194-0400 I -        [initandlisten]

Comment: Are you successfully changed the /tmp permissions? with sudo maybe? what's retunrning: ls -ld /tmp

Comment: Ok.. did sudo mongo got this . 2017-07-02T11:11:22.435-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2017-07-02T11:11:22.435-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2017-07-02T11:11:22.435-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2017-07-02T11:11:22.435-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2017-07-02T11:11:22.435-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]

Comment: 2017-07-02T11:11:22.435-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000
2017-07-02T11:11:22.439-0400 I FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
2017-07-02T11:11:22.439-0400 I NETWORK  [thread1] waiting for connections on port 27017
2017-07-02T11:11:23.017-0400 I FTDC     [ftdc] Unclean full-time diagnostic data capture shutdown detected, found interim file, some metrics may have been lost. OK . ... I can't type mongo cause its still running

Comment: No, not sudo  wuth mongod. There, it works but with warning, I mean sudo with changing permission on /tmp ,  you shouldnt launch it as root but needs to change /tmp permissions: sudo chmod 1777 /tmp

Comment: i tried sudo chmod 1777 /tmp  on chmod then run it with mongo and still get this .   /....2017-07-02T11:17:59.440-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5189 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Chriss-MBP
2017-07-02T11:17:59.441-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.5
2017-07-02T11:17:59.441-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 520b8f3092c48d934f0cd78ab5f40fe594f96863
2017-07-02T11:17:59.441-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2l  25 May 2017
2017-07-02T11:17:59.441-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system

Comment: 2017-07-02T11:17:59.441-0400 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock Resource temporarily unavailable. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating
2017-07-02T11:17:59.441-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2017-07-02T11:17:59.441-0400 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2017-07-02T11:17:59.441-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2017-07-02T11:17:59.441-0400 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
Chriss-MBP:~ Chris$

Comment: even with mongod exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to lock file: /data/db/mongod.lock Resource temporarily unavailable. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminatin still got this... how do i know whats . What's retunrning: ls -ld /tmp

Comment: Then mongodb started. connect with mongo now, it should work

Comment: ok.. why when i run mongo i get this . whats does it mean..2017-07-02T11:33:21.286-0400 W -        [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
2017-07-02T11:33:21.287-0400 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Permission denied
2017-07-02T11:33:21.287-0400 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578 at src/mongo/util/net/listen.cpp 195
2017-07-02T11:33:21.287-0400 I -        [initandlisten] 

.. and thank you for responding consistent.

Comment: Thank you for the help.. I can only run the data base when i use sudo.. but at least it narrow down whats wrong with it.       sudo chmod 1777 /tmp  help 
 then i use sudo chown -R `id -u` /data/db.. Thank again. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305279/dont-want-to-have-to-start-mongod-with-sudo-mongod