# Trying to run my project on localhost – how can I use "mongod" command in Mac terminal instead of "sudo mongod"?

Tags: mongodb, macos, terminal, sudo

*(NOT A DUPLICATE: This question title looks very similar to [Dont want to have to start mongod with `sudo mongod`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305279/dont-want-to-have-to-start-mongod-with-sudo-mongod), but they are slightly different problems, and that question did not have any approved answers and I don't want to try something unapproved if I don't know what it will do.)*

---

I am using mongodb and I am trying to run it on a localhost.

Supposedly, I should do `$ mongod` first in one terminal tab, then `$ turbo devserver` in another terminal tab, and this should run my project on a localhost.
However, when I try `$ mongod`, a bunch of text I don't understand shows up and in the midst of this text I see the following exception:

`exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating`

However, when I instead do `$ sudo mongod` it runs perfectly and I can see my project data in the localhost. But I don't want to have to use sudo, I want to be able to just use the `$ mongod` command.

I looked around on stackoverflow and although there were similar problems (but with a different exception), nothing really helped me. I am very new to mongodb/APIs/JS/JSON/etc. so it was hard to understand what some of the other posts were talking about.

---

## **In a nutshell**

#### What I'm trying to do:

1. Use `$ mongod` command on Mac terminal to set up database access
2. Use `$ turbo devserver` to successfully connect database to localhost

#### What is happening:

1. `$ mongod` command returns `IllegalOperation` exception
2. Therefore `$ turbo devserver` returns `DB Connection Failed!`
3. Database not connected, can't see project data in localhost

#### What I want to happen:

1. `$ mongod` to return `waiting for connections on port 27017` ...
2. ...which would make `$ turbo devserver` return `DB Successfully Connected!` ...
3. ...which would show my project data in localhost

#### What I've tried:

1. Using `$ sudo mongod` instead, which works, but I want only `$ mongod`

---

Help is much appreciated. Thanks community!

Comment: Why the "not a duplicate" rant at the beginning of the question? Have you asked the same question before and have been pointed to that answer? If so ( or even if you have not ) why does that answer **not apply** to you? I see nothing in your question that suggests you even attempted to change the assigned user or other permission levels on the `mongod` executable, as the answer is telling you to do. The reason why *"`sudo` **works**"* as you put it is simply because the "root user" has permissions your own user account does not. Change the permissions, or add your own account to to the group

Comment: Again, that question did not have any accepted answers and I don't want to try something unaccepted if I don't know what it will do. I am new to this; thus, since the two questions have different exceptions, I could not know if it applies to me. I wouldn't want to try something that turns out to be incorrect, and then not know how to revert it.

Your answer confuses me; this Mac has one user, why wouldn't it have permission?

To answer your question, I have not asked this question before but worried that I would simply be redirected to that question, as I am aware of Stackoverflow's rules.

Comment: @NeilLunn
I simply thought asking a knowledgeable, supportive community of coders would be more expedient than waiting until I've learned enough to accurately judge the usefulness of either or both of the answers to the other question.

Comment: MongoDB installs under it's own user account. Your Mac is actually a "unix based" ( or "unix like" ) and as such has the same "multiple users" and thus same user and group structure of all "like" systems. So all of the "many available answers" ( accepted or not does not mean incorrect ) that talk about "user permissions" and group assignments ALL APPLY here. `sudo` is basically an override to become the "superuser" with access to everything, and thus should only be used sparingly. And the **knowlegeable and supportive** people really should not need to answer the same thing over and over.

Comment: So to be sure, all I do is `sudo chmod -R 777 /data/db` and `sudo chown -R 'id -u' /data/db` (from other post)? Thanks for helping. On a side note, while "unaccepted" does not necessarily mean incorrect, it does indeed leave doubt—that's why Stackoverflow lets users accept answers. That green check tells people "look no further, this works for sure". I didn't know those answers "ALL APPLY" here. You're clearly more educated on computers; what's obvious to you may be entirely unbeknown to me. In the future, understand we are not all pros and sometimes need extra guidance. That's why we're here.